# QListWidget deselection and multiple selection

Tags: pyqt4, qlistwidget

i'm just searching in the docu and can not find the solution for the following two problems with `QListWidget`:

a) i would like to deselect (deactivate) items in the QListWidget from the software (i mean code)

b) i use multiple selection: `setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)`
I would like to pre-select more than one item from the code. If i use
`setCurrentRow()` i can only select on item (it toggles the selected item). How can i do multiple selections?

Your help is very welcome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both of those could be done with the [`setSelected`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidgetitem.html#setSelected) method of `QListWidgetItem`s.

```
# select item
listWidget.item(row).setSelected(True)

# deselect item
listWidget.item(row).setSelected(False)
```

You can do this for multiple items and as long as you have `MultipleSelection` enabled, it would select/deselect those items.

Comment: FYI to anybody else looking. This is how you enable MultipleSelections. listWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection );